# how do you center container vertically and remove the scrollbar using CSS (while using min-height 100vh)

Tags: html, css

I'm new here and still learning how to develop websites using HTML and CSS.

I want my container to be centralized vertically and horizontally(I managed to do that with `margin: auto`) however I failed on doing it vertically.

I set the body to `min-height: 100vh`(in order to make my background image full-sized and stretched.

However, a scrollbar appears and I want to fix it.

Here's a reproducible version:

```html
<body>
  <style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: url(images/bg-mobile.svg) $Violet;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .container {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 30px auto;

    }
  </style>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <section class="middle">
      <div class="hero">
        <img src="images/illustration-mockups.svg" alt="illustration-mockups">
      </div>
      <main>
        <h1>
          Build The Community Your Fans Will Love
        </h1>
        <p>Huddle re-imagines the way we build communities. You have a voice, but so does your audience.
          Create connections with your users as you engage in genuine discussion.</p>
        <button class="register">Register</button>
      </main>
    </section>
    <div class="social">
      <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
      <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
      <i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <p class="attribution">
        Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>
        Coded by <a href="https://github.com/knychandra">knychandra</a>
      </p>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f9f20a0736.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7HHH.png)

Comment: You probably still have the default margins on the body, and/or some other elements, but it's hard to tell from just the screenshot. You should include your code when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide Scrollbar by using following line of code

```
container{
   overflow : hidden;
}
```

Comment: hi Ahmed, thank you for the reply.
I have managed hide the scrollbar, however i could not access the content below it.
any suggestion on making my container centered in the middle (vertically) ? thanks for the help, cheers